# Auto-start my program in administrative mode when system starts up without the UAC prompt

Tags: vb.net, uac, autostart

**My problem** :

I made a program and i have this program for example now under this directory : `"C:\Program Files (x86)\AppName"`, now in the program i'm saving some images in my program directory, but since this is in the `C` drive, it's giving me a `access denied` error, now i made the program to always run in administrative mode and that worked just fine, but also there is in my program a feature to auto-start my program when the system starts up using a registry key, but when the **"always run in administrative mode"** is ON, the program will **not** start even though there is a start-up key in the registry, and when the **"always run in administrative mode"** is OFF, it will start.

---

**What I have tried so far** :

I tried making an another executable file that will start when the system starts up and then it will run my main program and close it self and i knew that will work but now every time i start my computer, the User Access Control prompt  ask me if i trust this program even and that is not very user-friendly.

So i searched and i found that i can create scheduled task but i didn't find a lot of examples and but i tried creating one manually and it did work as wanted!

**But here is a code which didn't work :**

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler
```

---

```
 Using ts As New TaskService("\\RemoteServer")
    'Create a new task definition and assign properties
    Dim td As TaskDefinition = ts.NewTask()
    td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something"

    'Create a trigger that will fire the task at this time every other day
    td.Triggers.Add(New DailyTrigger() With {
        Key.DaysInterval = 2
    })

    'Create an action that will launch Notepad whenever the trigger fires
    td.Actions.Add(New ExecAction("notepad.exe", "c:\test.log", Nothing))

    'Register the task in the root folder
    ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("Test", td)
End Using
```

---

**And the problem with the code is :**

It couldn't find the `TaskService` and it has no use of the `TaskScheduler` library!

---

**Hope someone have some previous experience with that who can help me!**

Comment: I think the problem is `i'm saving some images in my program directory`.  Program Files is not for data and requires special permission.  The rest seems to be trying to hack around that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:

To use that code you've got to download the [**Managed Task Scheduler Wrapper**](https://github.com/dahall/TaskScheduler) first. Then to make it run with administrative privileges you've got to set the `RunLevel` to `TaskRunLevel.Highest` on your `TaskDefinition`:

```
td.Principal.RunLevel = TaskRunLevel.Highest
```

---

***However*** like [Plutonix says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47462457/auto-start-my-program-in-administrative-mode-when-system-starts-up-without-the-u#comment81879788_47462457) you shouldn't be writing files to the directory of your program (as that's usually located in the restricted `%ProgramFiles%` folder).

Instead, use the [**`%ProgramData%` directory**](https://www.howtogeek.com/278562/what-is-the-programdata-folder-in-windows/). You can get the path to it from your code via [**`Environment.GetFolderPath()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)

'Example:
Dim ConfigPath As String = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), "AppName")
Dim ImagePath As String = Path.Combine(ConfigPath, "MyImage.png")

If Directory.Exists(ConfigPath) = False Then Directory.CreateDirectory(ConfigPath)
```

Comment: I think that does make sense and i'm going to go with that, thanks!

Comment: @MousaAlfhaily : Glad we could help!